# Facing problem to understand the equivalence class concept.

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations, set-partition

Currently I am trying to understand the equivalence class from the Herstein's book. And I am facing problem to understand the concept and also can't understand the theorem given in the page number 8.
Book name is *Topics in algebra*, second edition.

> **Theorem 1.1.1.** 
>   The distinct equivalence classes of an equivalence relation on $A$ provide us with a decomposition $o$f A as a union of mutually disjoint subsets. 
>   Conversely, given a decomposition of $A$ as a union of mutually disjoint, nonempty subsets, we can define an equivalence relation on $A$ for which these subsets are the distinct equivalence classes.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517238/equivalence-relation-and-equivalence-class

Comment: Hernestein?  I don't think I have that textbook handy.  Maybe you should post a copy of the theorem you want explained.

Comment: As an example: take the integers $\mathbb{Z}$. Now, all even integers put into a class $[0]$ (which is formally just the set $\{...,-2,0,2,...\}$). All odd integers put in a class $[1]$. Now no integer is even and odd so these classes are disjoint. Furthermore all integers are either even or odd so every integer is in either $[0]$ or $[1]$ but not the other. The equivalence relation here is $a\sim b$ if $a,b$ have the same parity (evenness or oddness).

Comment: Quoting the theorem might give you an opportunity to highlight exactly what you don't understand. For instance, you claim to have problems, but it is hard to guess *exactly* what you need.

Comment: Which Hernstein's book. He has book called *Abstract Algebra* and also a book called *Topics in Algebra*. In addition to that, there are probably several editions - I have looked into my copies of both books and there is no theorem on page 8.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Hernestein, Hernstein, Bernstein ???   I guess you mean something else - see [here](http://www.amazon.com/Abstract-Algebra-I-N-Herstein/dp/0471368792).

Comment: @Sid Is the theorem I have added to your post the theorem you are interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice illustration of the concept is the following:

Think of $A$ as the collection of all people in the world. Think of an equivalence relation as "nationality", so two members of $A$ are equivalent in the sense that they have the same nationality (assuming for simplicity that everyone has unique nationality). This naturally decomposes $A$ into countries, i.e. collections of people grouped by nationality, and then the countries are precisely the equivalence classes. The theorem then reads:

The distinct countries provide us with a decomposition of all people of the world as a union of mutually disjoint groupings of people. Conversely, given a decomposition of the world as a union of mutually disjoint groupings of people, we can define an equivalence relation on the people of the world (= the nationality), for which the groupings by nationality are precisely the distinct countries.